# zone does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to create a server in Location Mumbai for past 2 months , I am getting Error in all 3 a,b,c zones.

When will the servers will be available in mumbai ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you've got an error message like:

```
The zone 'projects/XXX/zones/asia-south1-x' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.
```

while creating VM instances at `asia-south1-a`, `asia-south1-b` and `asia-south1-c`.

It's not an issue. Have a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances#vm-not-created) to find more details:

> If you receive a resource error (such as ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED
> or ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED_WITH_DETAILS) when requesting new
> resources, it means that the zone cannot currently accommodate your
> request. This error is due to Compute Engine resource obtainability,
> and is not due to your Compute Engine quota.

**The  reason for this behavior** is resource availability which depends from users requests and therefore are dynamic.

**There are a few ways to solve it**:

1. Choose [another zone](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-compute-engine-region-selection) for your instance.
2. Wait for a while and try to start your VM instance again.
3. [Reserve resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) for your VM by following documentation to avoid such issue in future:

> Create reservations for Virtual Machine (VM) instances in a specific
> zone, using custom or predefined machine types, with or without
> additional GPUs or local SSDs, to ensure resources are available for
> your workloads when you need them. *After you create a reservation, you
> begin paying for the reserved resources immediately*, and they remain
> available for your project to use indefinitely, until the reservation
> is deleted.

Comment: I want mumbai only , when will datacenter will be free ?

Comment: As I wrote above, it depends from users requests. As a result, there's no way to know in advance available capacity of particular zones. You can try to reach [Google Cloud Sales Team](https://cloud.google.com/contact) and ask for resources reservation to avoid issues related to on-demand access.

Comment: I am using Flexible and today was experiencing the ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED error for hours while trying to boot my application up. Do you know if I could I use reservations in this scenario (flexible)?